# Crear tabla Json con una clase php

Tags: php, json

Estoy creando una tabla a partir de unos datos que estan en un archivo .json y tengo este código

```
<body>
    <?php include "mostrar_tabla.php";?>
<div class="container">
<div class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableHeading">
        <div class="divTableCell">ID</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Nombre</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Ingreso</div>
        <div class="divTableCell">Puesto</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableBody">
    <?php
     /*ME FALTARA ALGO AQUI*/
        foreach($trabajadores as $empleado){
        echo "<div class='divTableRow'>";
            echo "<div class='divTableCell'>$empleado[ID]</div>";
            echo "<div class='divTableCell'>$empleado[Nombre]</div>";
            echo "<div class='divTableCell'>$empleado[Ingreso]</div>";
            echo "<div class='divTableCell'>$empleado[Puesto]</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <p>Empleados en total <strong><?= $hay; ?></strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

mostrar_tabla.php

```
<?php
class create_table {

public static function c_table() {

$contenido = file_get_contents("tabla_ajax.json");
$con = utf8_encode($contenido);
$datos = json_decode($con, true);

$hay = count($datos["empleados"]); //Para el contador
$trabajadores = $datos["empleados"];
}
}
?>
```

El problema que tengo es que no me carga los datos en la tabla.
Anteriormente tenia la funcion metida directamente en el html y funciona, pero necesito pasarla a una clase para poder utilizarla siempre que la necesite. 
No estoy muy familiarizado con las clases y los objetos aun.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Opción 1**

Dentro del método estático de tu class, tienes mas de un elemento que deseas retornar, entonces para lograr eso debería lucir de este modo:

```
public static function c_table() {
    $propiedad1 = "valor1";
    $propiedad2 = "valor2";
    return array($propiedad1, $propiedad2);
}
```

Lo anterior debido a que requieres mas de un valor para trabajarlo en tu vista.

Siguiente necesitas inicializar tu clase, para poder acceder a dichos elementos; pudiera ser de este modo:

```
create_table::c_table();
```

Con lo anterior ya la propiedad `$trabajadores` debería estar disponible para usar en tu vista

**Opción 2**

Dentro del método retornas las propiedades dentro de un array asociativo, de modo que podamos recuperar sus valores por medio de sus claves de este modo:

```
public static function c_table() {
    $hay = count($datos["empleados"]); //Para el contador
    $trabajadores = $datos["empleados"];
    return array("hay" => $hay, "trabajadores" => $trabajadores);
}
```

Posterior inicializas la clase de este modo, accediendo al método por medio del operador de [*resolución de ámbito*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) identificado por los dobles dos puntos `::`

```
$trabajador = create_table::c_table();
```

Pudiendo recuperar los valores del array de este modo:

```
$trabajador["hay"]; //para el conteo
$trabajador["trabajadores"]//para los registros recuperados;
```

**Iterar los datos de la clave `trabajadores` en la variable `$trabajador`**

Para ahora iterar los datos que recupera `$trabajador` en la clave `trabajadores` pudiera quedar una estructura en el `foreach()` de este modo:

```
foreach($trabajador["trabajadores"] as $valor){
    echo $valor["nombreTrabajador"];
}
```

> `nombreTrabajador` será el nombre de la clave que quieres recuperar e imprimir de tu archivo leído

Comment: Siendo 4 valores los que quiero retornar, "id", "nombre", "ingreso" y "puesto" debo de poner 4 $propiedadX?

Comment: @Vyrtu espero mi última actualización te ayude

Comment: Ya está! Muchisimas gracias! No entendia como recorrer luego con el foreach pero foreach($trabajador["trabajadores"] as $valor) era la solución :)